# Implementing drag and swipe transition between two UiViewControllers and UIViews?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller

So two questions.

1) There's a few apps out there where you can drag and swipe between an entire view controllers by dragging the left and right edges of the UIVIew. Once you're done drag gin, it shows about 10% previous view controller and 90% of the new view controller for you. A great example is the Facebook app, where you swipe to the left and the chat box appears, how would you do something like this? I attached an image for clarification.

[image]

2) Another question I have is implementing this drag and swipe transition to just UIViews (or subviews), not the entire UIViewController. An example of this is iFunny (kind of), where you can swipe between UIImagesView but the actual UIViewController or parent UIView doesn't change, just the subview.

So my question is what classes are associated with these transitions? I've been looking into UIPageViewController, not sure if that works though. Also, can i do this in storyboard?

Thank you for your time!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path

For the second question:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: Awesome, I guess there's no storyboard way to go about a slide out navigation. I'll look into iCarousel! Would you happen to have any visual examples of iCarousel in action?

Comment: There are over a dozen examples in the github repo, including a barebones basic example, to one that downloads images, to another with nested iCarousels, etc.

Comment: Please mark this one as correct if you are satisfied with the answer.